# Cannot .loc a Multindex with tuple values in one level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multindex. One of the levels of the multiindex has a tuple as a value.

When I try to IndexSlice based on the tuple,  I never get any results.

I'm suspicious the tuple is being interpreted weirdly (not as a simple label, but as some other instruction to IndexSlice).

Toy example to demonstrate:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

foo =  ["alpha", "bravo", "tango"]
bar =  ["mike", "matt", "dave"]
pair = [(1,2), (8,7), (12,14)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([foo, bar, pair],  names=['foo', 'bar', 'pair'])
zf = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
zf['filler']=range(3*3*3)


zf.loc[idx[:, "mike", :],:]   #ok
zf.loc[idx['bravo', :, :],:]   #ok
zf.loc[idx['bravo', 'mike', :],:]   #ok
zf.loc[idx[:,:, (8,7)],:]  #returns nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one `[]` around tuple:

```
print (zf.loc[idx[:,:, [(8,7)]],:])
                   filler
foo   bar  pair          
alpha mike (8, 7)       1
      matt (8, 7)       4
      dave (8, 7)       7
bravo mike (8, 7)      10
      matt (8, 7)      13
      dave (8, 7)      16
tango mike (8, 7)      19
      matt (8, 7)      22
      dave (8, 7)      25
```